# Selecting/casting output as integer in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, int

I'm working on a site that requires me to display a graph of the average number per day of a user input. I have a SQL query already that returns this info to me:

```
SELECT sum(number)/count(number) as average, date FROM stats WHERE * GROUP BY date
```

This gives me the result I am looking for, but the result is given with three decimals precision. I want to round of this number. I could do it in PHP or my template engine, of course, but I was curious if there was a way to do this all in the database.

Is there a way to cast an output as an integer (in MySQL)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, any reason you're not using [AVG function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)?

Comment: @jimmy_keen had no idea that existed! Is there a reason to use it? (better, faster, stronger?)

Comment: @MrGlass - More concise and avoids possible divide by zero problems in other RDBMSs (AFAIK MySQL returns `NULL` on a divide by zero anyway)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  CAST(sum(number)/count(number) as UNSIGNED) as average, 
  date 
FROM stats 
WHERE * 
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: -1. If you use "INT" as type you will get an error. The available types for CAST/CONVERT can be seen in the documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

Comment: Thats matters? The approach is answering the Q.

Comment: @alex on MySQL 5.5 (latest version on some repositories) it will result in a 1064 error. It might work on some newer versions, although it doesn't seem to be documented

Answer (score 29):

The valid types for a [`CAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html) in MySQL are as follows

- `BINARY[(N)]`
- `CHAR[(N)]`
- `DATE`
- `DATETIME`
- `DECIMAL[(M[,D])]`
- `SIGNED [INTEGER]`
- `TIME`
- `UNSIGNED [INTEGER]`

So you could use

```
SELECT CAST(sum(number)/count(number) AS UNSIGNED) as average...
```

Or `SIGNED` if the `SUM` part can ever add up to a negative number.

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`DIV` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_div).

```
mysql> SELECT 5 DIV 2;
    -> 2
```

> Integer division. Similar to FLOOR(), but is safe with BIGINT values. Incorrect results may occur for noninteger operands that exceed BIGINT range.

Answer (score 7):

how about using MySQL `FORMAT` Function?

```
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12345.123456, 4);
+-------------------------+
| FORMAT(12345.123456, 4) |
+-------------------------+
| 12,345.1235             |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12345.123456, 0);
+-------------------------+
| FORMAT(12345.123456, 0) |
+-------------------------+
| 12,345                  |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT convert(int, sum(number)/count(number)) as average,
  date
FROM stats
WHERE * GROUP BY date
```

or

```
SELECT 
  CAST(sum(number)/count(number) as INT) as average, 
  date 
FROM stats 
WHERE * 
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

1. User mysql function round()
2. Example round(23.33) will return 23 in msyql.

Your example query will be updated to

```
SELECT round(sum(number)/count(number)) as average, date FROM stats WHERE * GROUP BY date
```