# Is there any way to work as integer in sql server in all databases

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-server-2008, database-migration

I m working on Database migration... where i m changing quires according to SQL.
so the queries should be work on all databases. 
here is the query , that can i make to work in all databases.

```
select STD_ID from SCHOOL order by cast(STD_ID as integer)
```

This is the query working fine in SQL SERVER 2008, but it is not working MySQL,
is there any way to change above query that should work on all databases.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you looking for a query that works in both SQL Server and MySQL? It's possible to do, but we need to know more to help you. Can you share the CREATE TABLE statement for SCHOOL and some INSERT statements with sample data?

Comment: use `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED` for mysql.

Comment: [Not possible to use a single query for both without changing the semantics](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8895995/73226). `cast(STD_ID as DECIMAL(10,0))` would work in both but might cause other issues.

Comment: Of course you should just fix `SCHOOL` to have the correct datatype for  `STD_ID` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `STD_ID` is some sort of string, you may be able to use:

```
select STD_ID from SCHOOL order by STD_ID+0
```

I've tested this on SQLFiddle with both MySQL and SQLServer and they both seem to correctly do an implicit cast to `INT`.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look in the MySQL docs about casting: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

It looks like 'integer' is called 'signed' (or of course  'unsigned') in MySQL.

I'm no (My)SQL wizard, but doing a Google search for "mysql cast to integer" yielded the above.