# Select/Fetch signed integer in PostgreSQL/Python

Tags: python, postgresql, casting, tuples, psycopg2

I would like to Select and Fetch integer from the column *measurement_id* of the table *measurements*, since otherwise, I have somehow convert one-item-size tuple to signed integer by some postprocess of Python.
I know this [Selecting/casting output as integer in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895927/selecting-casting-output-as-integer-in-sql) in MySQL where my pseudocode for PostgreSQL 9.4

```
CREATE TABLE measurements (
        measurement_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        measurement_size_in_bytes INTEGER NOT NULL,
        time TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);  

-- sample data
INSERT INTO measurements (measurement_size_in_bytes) VALUES (77777), (5065), (888);

SELECT CAST(measurement_id AS SIGNED) FROM measurements ORDER BY time desc limit 1;
```

where casting is not working, not even by `measurement_id::int`. 
Probably, `format` is the right tool here.
Doing `print "measurement_id ", _measurement_id;` gives tuple (`(21,)`), while it should just give `21`.

### Initiating and Running in Python

```
sudo -u postgres psql detector -f 12.7.2015_creates.sql;
DROP TABLE
CREATE TABLE
$ sudo -u postgres psql detector -c "INSERT INTO measurements (measurement_size_in_bytes) VALUES (77777), (5065), (888);"
INSERT 0 3
$ sudo -u postgres psql detector -c "INSERT INTO measurements (measurement_size_in_bytes) VALUES (77777), (5065), (888);"
INSERT 0 3
$ sudo -u postgres psql detector -c "SELECT measurement_id FROM measurements ORDER BY time desc limit 1";
 measurement_id 
----------------
              7
(1 row)
```

but doing the same in Python where I need to use the data

```
import sys
import os
import struct
import psycopg2
conn_string = "dbname=detector user=postgres password=1234 host=localhost port=5432"
print "Connecting to database\n    ->%s" % (conn_string)     
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(
    'SELECT measurement_id FROM measurements ORDER BY time desc limit 1;'
);
_measurement_id = cursor.fetchone();
print "measurement_id ", _measurement_id, " javist!";
```

returning

```
Connecting to database
    ->dbname=detector user=postgres password=1234 host=localhost port=5432
measurement_id  (11,)  javist!
```

I would like to have from print `measurement_id  11  javist!`.

How can you select/fetch signed int from tuple in PostgreSQL/Python?

OS: Debian 8.5
Hardware: Lenovo

Comment: you mean `measurement_id` is *not* an int? Why not?

Comment: Edit your question and add the `create table` statement for `measurements` and ideally some sample data ( as `insert` statements)  that reproduce this behaviour. `cast(.. as signed)` is not valid for Postgres, because `signed` is not a valid data type in Postgres

Comment: It would help if you showed us what `measurement` actually is.

Comment: Both the insert and select won't execute. The insert tries to put data in a non existing column and the select uses the type SIGNED which does not exists in postgresql. Also I do not see the reason for the cast. measurement_id is declared as a serial which is an integer with a default value from a sequence and integers are signed.

Comment: Ok, can you also fix the SELECT so it will execute and show the problem?

Comment: Seems a python problem to me, postgres will give normal result for this query. I do not know python but my guess is that fetchone returns one row so you are printing a row not a single value. I suspect you need to retieve the measurement_id  field from the row and print that.

Comment: @Eelke If it could be done with one fetch, that would save resources, since no postprocessing needed then by Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetchone` returns a tuple. Just get its first element:

```
_measurement_id = cursor.fetchone()[0];
```